# Run a batch file on remote servers

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which stops a service and deletes a file from d:\ drive.
I want to execute this on 20 servers.
Is there a quicker way than manually logging on each server, copying and running batch file?

Answer (score 6):

You could try using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). 
If the batch file is present in all machines at same location, then you could mention the list of machines in a text file and give it as an argument to this.Something like,

```
psexec @<machines_list_file> <location to batch file on remote machines>
```

If you dont have it on remote machine, you need to copy the batch file and then execute it using,

```
psexec @<machines_list_file> -c <location to batch file in current machine>
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest writing a single local script that:

1. Uses `net start/start` \server to start/stop service remotely.
2. Deletes a file on `\\server\d$\...`

You can iterate over a list of server names and run those 2 commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could use psexec from sysinternals http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx