# How would I write a batch script that would restart a windows service across multiple servers?

Tags: batch-file

Very new to batch scripts. I know how to stop and start a service, but I'm not certain how I would make the script perform the stop/start across multiple servers.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/116916/run-a-batch-file-on-remote-servers?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

1. With some kind of management software (like [SCCM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/system-center-configuration-manager)).
2. With [PSExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg697102.aspx).
3. With [Powershell Remoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands).